# Where can I find the 'build' command needed to build the environment for EDK 2?

Tags: compiling

I followed the step-by-step article here: [UEFI/EFK2](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/UEFI/EDK2) . Everything works nice until I need to actually build it. At the paragraph 'Building MdeModulePkg module package' the description says: Just type build:

```
bash$ build
```

but my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS says:

```
No command 'build' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xbuild' from package 'mono-xbuild' (main)
 Command 'guild' from package 'guile-2.0-libs' (universe)
 Command 'sbuild' from package 'sbuild' (universe)
 Command 'bwild' from package 'bacula-director-common' (main)
 Command 'buildd' from package 'buildd' (universe)
build: command not found
```

Maybe someone knows where exactly I can find this mysterious command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have installed the build dependencies and followed [the guide](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/UEFI/EDK2) exactly, I think you just need to make sure you are in the `edk2` directory when you issue the `build` command. If you enter the `build` command when you are in any other directory you will get the error that you received.

Also, the `build` command will only work if you have run `edksetup.sh` and edited the correct build parameters into  `~/src/edk2/Conf/target.txt` (or whatever your path is).

Here is the initial output of the build command when run from the `edk2` directory (with files tweaked as per the guide):

```
mik@Acer ~/src/edk2$ build
Build environment: Linux-3.2.0-32-generic-i686-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
Build start time: 00:45:15, Oct.22 2012

WORKSPACE        = /home/mike/src/edk2
ECP_SOURCE       = /home/mike/src/edk2/EdkCompatibilityPkg
EDK_SOURCE       = /home/mike/src/edk2/EdkCompatibilityPkg
EFI_SOURCE       = /home/mike/src/edk2/EdkCompatibilityPkg
EDK_TOOLS_PATH   = /home/mike/src/edk2/BaseTools

Architecture(s)  = IA32
Build target     = DEBUG
Toolchain        = GCC46

Active Platform          = /home/mike/src/edk2/MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc

Processing meta-data ........... done!
```

Then it proceeds to compile everything required.

Comment: 'build' is a script ? executable file ? Here is step-by-step description of what I did:  http://pastebin.com/MJJs7nSQ

Comment: @Jasper  It seems to be a script that creates the Makefile; you will still get the error if the options are not set correctly in target.txt- I think that is probably where the problem is. I just changed the options and now I get the same error, whereas when I change them back again, build works. Also, are you using git for the source, as that is what I did?

Comment: Thanks Mik. I guess I found the problem - it's seems that 'build' script located in /BaseTools/BinWrappers/ dir but somehow it doesn't added to $PATH so I guess bash doesn't know how/where from to run it.. I'll check it

Comment: Anyway - most of the tutorials related to Windows based build process (even in manual: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tianocore/index.php?title=EDK_II_white_papers ) Build Process Decoded they explain Windows build **only**. So I guess I switch to Windows platform

Comment: @Jasper Ok. I suppose that the issue is solved for us now on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use

```
bash:~/src/edk2$ source edksetup.sh

bash:~/src/edk2$ build
```

The effect of export command inside edksetup.sh is not reflected in the main bash shell but rather in the sub-shell spawned for executing it. "source" directs it to run the script in current shell.